# Connect to IPSec VPN via secondary interface

Tags: ubuntu, route, iproute

I need to route the connection through an IPSec VPN by a second interface (`eth1`)

- eth0 is my default gateway to the Internet
- eth1 is connected to an IPSec VPN router

Setup for first interface (default route):

- Gateway 192.168.100.1/24
- eth0: 192.168.100.2/24

Setup for secondary interface

- eth1: 192.168.51.10/24
- vpn router: 192.168.51.1/24

VPN endpoints

- local: 192.168.51.0/24
- remote: 172.16.0.0/26

I need to connect to the remote 172.16.0.151 by eth1.

Comment: try `sudo route add default gw 192.168.51.1 eth1` , also your vpn server's config file should have an option like `push "route 192.168.51.0 255.255.255.0"` , at least openvpn does, I am sure that ipsec has a similar option.

Comment: @Chev_603 OpenVPN and IPsec are totally different beasts. But in this question the IPsec component is completely irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Does that mean that IPSec servers do not have the option to "push" routes to the clients the way that OpenVPN servers do..? I admit I've never tried to set up an IPSec tunnel before. I just imagined that it would work similarly. Just curious.

Comment: @Chev_603 IPSec tunnels are one of the most awkward and annoying parts of infrastructure I have had the misfortune to encounter. If they are not set up absolutely precisely they will fail. Without particularly good error messages. If you get it only mostly right it's possible they'll work until the rekeying interval expires, and then they'll break. For bonus points you also have to be sure that your two endpoints can talk the same flavour of IPSec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a route to the remote network via the local network address of the appropriate router.

New style

```
ip route add to 172.16.0.0/26 via 192.168.51.1 dev eth1
```

Old style

```
route add -net 172.16.0.0/26 gw 192.168.51.1 dev eth1
```

Actually, since the kernel can infer the interface name from the routing table entry for the subnet 192.168.51.0/24 you don't actually need the `dev eth1`. But there's no harm including it and it will fail safely if your network configuration is changed at a later date.

Comment: thaks to all, that's works like a charm.